# Escaping Angle Brackets in Razor

Tags: c#, razor

I have the following code

```
var template1 = @"< god@@heaven.org";
var content1 = Razor.Parse(template1);
Console.WriteLine(content1);
var template2 = @"god@@heaven.org";
var content2 = Razor.Parse(template2);
Console.WriteLine(content2);
```

Which outputs

```
< god@@heaven.org
god@heaven.org
```

It looks like razor thinks I am within a tag and so not escaping the @ sign.  How can I escape the left angle bracket?

Comment: tried, but didn't work because I am not producing HTML, just a file for some downstream code to parse..

Comment: That would have been important to know sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't used Razor in this way, but I'm thinking something like:

```
var template1 = @"@Html.Raw(\"<\") god@@heaven.org"
```

May force it to do what you want.  Alternatively, some post-process hackery may do:

```
var template1 = @"&lt; god@@heaven.org";
var content1 = Razor.Parse(template).Replace("&lt;","<")
```